# How to import and export with React cdn?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, cdn, react-component

Does anyone know if you can export/import a component using the React cdn?

I'm trying to export a class component from another file so that I can route/link to it.

```
class RouteC extends React.Component {
  btnClickA() {
    browserHistory.push('/a');
  }

  btnClickB() {
    browserHistory.push('/b');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Route C</h2>
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={ this.btnClickA }>Goto A</button>
          <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={ this.btnClickB }>Goto B</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={RouteA} />
    <Route path="/a" component={RouteA} />
    <Route path="/b" component={RouteB} />
    <Route path="/c" component={RouteC} />
    <Route path="*" component={RouteA} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I'm trying to do something similar to this (https://codepen.io/lsmoura/pen/pNPOzp), but imagine if components A and B are in separate files.

I've already tried using *export default class* but that produced an error. From my search it has something to do with CommonJS and ES6. I don't want to use webpack or browserify as I'm not sure how to integrate that with my backend which is Flask. Any suggestions or help would be deeply appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire `RouteA` class component into another file `/src/Components/RouteA`, add `import React from 'react';` and add `export default RouteA`. Final version should be as below

```js
import React from 'react';

class RouteA extends React.Component {
  btnClickB() {
    browserHistory.push('/b');
  }
  btnClickC() {
    browserHistory.push('/c');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Route A</h2>
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={ this.btnClickB }>Goto B</button>
          <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={ this.btnClickC }>Goto C</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RouteA;
```

Then import `RouteA` when you need it.

`import RouteA from './src/Components/RouteA';`

Comment: I don't think you can use import/export statements with the cdn? Unless I need ES6 installed?